# Date wise listing of hadoop file in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I did :

> hadoop dfs -ls /user/abc/fun/

and it worked fine and listed all files in increasing order alphabetically.
I want listing of files according to date in increasing order i.e. latest date file be placed at bottom

something like this:

> hadoop dfs -ls ltrh /user/abc/fun/

It didn't worked as I read pig's wiki that this is not a valid FSshell command.
Please suggest how to get the desired result.
Any help would be appreciated.Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of ways to do it

- If you want to do it inside Pig Shell and not script Just Save the following command `hadoop fs -ls /user/abc/fun/ | sort -k6,7` inside a `test.sh` file. Give it `chmod +x` permissions then from inside the grunt shell you can do `sh ./test.sh` do get the desired result.
- Suppose you want to include this inside a `pig` script and run it using `pig -f` then you can simply use `%declare baseDir hadoop fs -ls /user/abc/fun/ | sort -k6,7 | tail -1`

Comment: What `sort -k6,7' do exactly.Please elaborate.Thanks

Comment: this query also works well:                                     hadoop dfs -ls /user/abc/fun/ | sort

Comment: sort -k6,7 sorts the output of hadoop dfs -ls by 6,7 column which are essentially the data and time fields. And that's exactly what you want